# How to move classic resources to a new location?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager

I have a cloud service and a storage account deployed using the classic resource manager in the East US region; there is also a classic backup vault in the West Europe region.

Due to high latency, I want to move all of these resources to the UK South region, which is the closest one to me and others using these services. I have created a new resource group in the UK South region, however, when I try to move my existing classic resources to the new resource group, it says:

> Classic resources must be moved separately and aren't displayed below.

Reading the article it linked to, it says that to move classic resources when experiencing this limitation, I need to contact support to have this operation done manually.

I do not have a support plan and am hoping not to buy one for this single task. Is there any other way around this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can walk around it by:
1. Create a new blank cloud service in your new resource group in UK South region.
2. Modify the deployment process to deploy the code to the newly created cloud service.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that it is limited by Azure. The following is snippet from the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#classic-deployment-limitations).
When moving resources from one resource group to another resource group within the same subscription, the following restrictions apply:

> Virtual networks (classic) cannot be moved.
>
> Virtual machines (classic) must be moved with the cloud service.
>
> Cloud service can only be moved when the move includes all its virtual machines.
>
> Only one cloud service can be moved at a time.
>
> Only one storage account (classic) can be moved at a time.
>
> Storage account (classic) cannot be moved in the same operation with a virtual machine or a cloud service.

As Toan nguyen mentioned that we need to redeploy it if you don't want to call Azure Support.